# Does stb_image simd support exist?

Tags: c++, c, jpeg, simd

stb_image appears to have support for plug-in SIMD implementation(s) of the idct and ycbcr->rgb conversion operations, which take majority of time when loading jpeg files. Looking at the code behind STBI_SIMD it's pretty clear this code has actually been used somewhere.

However, either the implementations have been proprietary, or my google-fu fails me, as I haven't found any public code that uses this interface.

My needs would be for the x86 platform only (at this time).

Is there any open source that uses this interface?

Comment: If it was his code, he would undoubtedly have included it (or a link to it, if with different license).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember seeing your question on Twitter, where today coincidently someone mentioned [libjpeg-turbo](http://libjpeg-turbo.virtualgl.org/) licensed under the BSD license. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to belong to the Horde3D engine (GNU LGPL)

http://open-projects.net/~shahn/darcs/old/Horde3D_Linux_64bit/Horde3D/Source/Horde3D%20Engine/utImage.cpp

although I was expecting SSE, SIMD at its purest..

Comment: utImage.cpp appears to just include copy of the stb_image source, and not any simd code; I don't see any in the horde3d project either, and makefiles don't seem to define the STBI_SIMD macro.

Comment: SIMD = single instruction multiple data, taken literally might also mean doing the same bitwise instruction on a vector of data / array. It's not strictly related to SSE extension (Intel). Furthermore the signature of the idct_block matches the one you were searching for, might be a good spot.

Comment: I know all that. If you read the original question, the stb_image has a plug-in interface for optimized versions (likely assembly using some simd instruction set, such as mmx, sse, or similar vector ops on non-intel hardwre). The code you're pointing at is just a plain copy of stb_image with no such optimizations in use.

Comment: so you are searching for a SSE version or a similar one, right?

Comment: No, I'm searching for code that is written specifically for that plug-in interface.